# e.DetailsElement in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

is there any way i can  write  this  code in  a  function()
 right now  what is happening in function is
 it tells
**e.Row.DetailsVisibility**
**e.DetailsElement.ActualHeight**
it is not able  to  find  this  it is telling  is there any way i can get this
e.DetailsElement.ActualHeight

```
if (e.Row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    DataGrid datagrid = sender as DataGrid;
                    if (datagrid != null)
                    {
                        datagrid.Tag = e.DetailsElement.ActualHeight;
                        datagrid.Height = datagrid.ActualHeight + e.DetailsElement.ActualHeight;
                    }
                }
                );
            }
            else
            {
                DataGrid datagrid = sender as DataGrid;
                if(datagrid.Tag!=null)
                    datagrid.Height = datagrid.ActualHeight - System.Convert.ToDouble(datagrid.Tag);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having in mind that you explanation is not very clear, what's the problem to put that code in a function as follows:

```
public void yourFunction(object sender, theTypeOfArguments e )
{
    if (e.Row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            DataGrid datagrid = sender as DataGrid;
            if (datagrid != null)
            {
                datagrid.Tag = e.DetailsElement.ActualHeight;
                datagrid.Height = datagrid.ActualHeight + e.DetailsElement.ActualHeight;
            }
        }
        );
    }
    else
    {
        DataGrid datagrid = sender as DataGrid;
        if(datagrid.Tag!=null)
            datagrid.Height = datagrid.ActualHeight - System.Convert.ToDouble(datagrid.Tag);

    }
}
```

If that's not your question please give more clarifications.